# SQL state: 22P02 invalid input syntax for integer error in recursive PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, recursion

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am currently in the process of writing a recursive function to find tram times.

I have defined a custom type as:

```
CREATE TYPE single_journey AS
   (tram_id integer,
    departure_station text,
    departure_time time without time zone,
    destination_station text,
    arrival_time time without time zone);
```

and the function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_tram_same_line(text, text, time) returns single_journey AS  $$
DECLARE
     departure_station ALIAS FOR $1;
     destination_station ALIAS FOR $2;
     query_time ALIAS FOR $3;

     journey single_journey;
BEGIN
     journey.departure_station := departure_station;
     journey.destination_station := destination_station;

     SELECT tram_id, time 
     INTO journey.tram_id, journey.departure_time
     FROM station_departure_times
     JOIN stations on station_departure_times.station_id = stations.station_id
     WHERE stations.name = departure_station
     AND time > query_time
     ORDER BY time ASC
     LIMIT 1;

     SELECT time 
     INTO journey.arrival_time
     FROM station_departure_times
     JOIN stations on station_departure_times.station_id = stations.station_id
     WHERE stations.name = destination_station
     AND tram_id = journey.tram_id;

     IF journey.arrival_time IS NULL THEN
           SELECT find_tram_same_line(
                departure_station, 
                destination_station, 
                (query_time + interval '1 minute'))
           INTO journey;
     END IF;

     RETURN journey;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The query:

```
SELECT find_tram_same_line('GrimesDyke', 'CitySquare', '09:00:00');
```

Whenever I run the query, I get an error:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "(24,GrimesDyke,09:07:00,CitySquare,10:19:00)"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: PL/pgSQL function find_tram_same_line(text,text,time without time zone) line 29 at SQL statement
```

I have spent some time trying to figure out why this is to no avail. The only integer in the single_journey type is the tram_id but I am unsure why this is causing an issue. Does anyone know why this might be?

Edit: Should be noted that (24,GrimesDyke,09:07:00,CitySquare,10:19:00) is what I was expecting.

Comment: Which line is line 29?

Comment: `SELECT find_tram_same_line(` The start of the recursive call I think.

Comment: Not sure, but try changing it to `SELECT * FROM find_tram_same_line(...`

Comment: Maybe try: `journey := find_tram_same_line(...);` instead of the `select .. into`

Comment: That did it! But why?

Comment: Because `SELECT func_returns_row()` will return with only one column, which is row-type (or record-type). If you add an `INTO` clause for that, PostgreSQL will try to create a record in which the first column is also a record (and all others are `NULL`). But it cannot do that, because the types are not compatible. Both `SELECT * FROM func_returns_row() INTO record` and the assignment with `:=` should work.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but you could solve your original problem with a simple self-join. You don't need to use a recursive function for this (if this is not just a simplification of a larger problem).

Comment: @pozs thanks for your comment, got a similar response from the pgsql-novice mailing list: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKyoTgYLzprs_P49pQwOR+9eVjr3eK3pBgK=w=7ezWn2Sytdjg@mail.gmail.com How would the self-join work?

Comment: The whole idea is that, because you want 2 (somewhat related) data from a single table, you do a join on the table itself, like `SELECT ... FROM station_departure_times departure JOIN station_departure_times destination USING (tram_id)` then you can search for a specific (departure-destination) pair using the `WHERE` clause.